# Manage multiple include files in PHP

Tags: php, include, dreamweaver, code-organization

I have a main.php file which has the following three included php files:

```
    <!--TAB 1--->
    <?php include "tab1.php"; ?>        
    <!--TAB 2--->
    <?php include "tab2.php"; ?>                      
    <!--TAB 3--->
    <?php include "tab3.php"; ?>
```

When I open main.php in Dreamweaver, I have access to these 3 included files.  My question is:  What about files that are included inside one of these include files?

For example, the tab2.php file reference these php files:

```
    <?php include "a.php"; ?>        
    <?php include "b.php"; ?>                      
    <?php include "c.php"; ?>
```

In order to be able to edit these included files which are inside another include file, what needs to be done?  Will I need to open those directly?

What I would like to be able to do is open main.php and then be able to add all 6 included files:

```
tab1.php
tab2.php
tab3.php
a.php
b.php
c.php
```

It seems as though I only have direct access to the first-level include files.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Just to get this clear... you are asking about having the code within the same open tab and not have opened multiple files for editing !? - So this is basically really dreamweaver-specific, right?

Comment: I understood the same. I think isn't related with programming...

Comment: Yep- a little confusing what you are asking for. I think you want to edit "a.php"? If you want to edit a.php- you need to have access to a.php. It also depends on your code. If it's procedural, then moving the location of your include can have some negative results. If it's an object definition, you can move your include statement to main.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Dreamweaver CS5, it has an (default enabled) option to show includes in a line below the file tabs. If you have an include that has other includes, the only way of editting this includes directly from this file is to press `CTRL+D` in the include, then Dreamweaver will show a popup for you to select the includes to edit and it will open the selected one in a tab.